# PySpark: "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java: Not a directory" (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run hello-world PySpark application.

I'm using PyCharm

Code of my `LOL.py` script:

```
  import os
    
    os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/opt/spark"
    
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    
    def init_spark():
      spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("HelloWorld").getOrCreate()
      sc = spark.sparkContext
      return spark,sc
    
    def main():
      spark,sc = init_spark()
      nums = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
      print(nums.map(lambda x: x*x).collect())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Output:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java: Not a directory
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/evgenii/PycharmProjects/bi-etl-orders/LOL.py", line 19, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/evgenii/PycharmProjects/bi-etl-orders/LOL.py", line 13, in main
        spark,sc = init_spark()
      File "/Users/evgenii/PycharmProjects/bi-etl-orders/LOL.py", line 8, in init_spark
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("HelloWorld").getOrCreate()
      File "/Users/evgenii/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
        sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
      File "/Users/evgenii/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 349, in getOrCreate
        SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
      File "/Users/evgenii/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
        SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
      File "/Users/evgenii/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 298, in _ensure_initialized
        SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
      File "/Users/evgenii/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
        raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    
    Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I know that "*Java gateway process exited before sending its port number*" is often raised because of incorrect setup of JAVA_HOME.

But I think this is not the case, because my JAVA_HOME looks pretty normal:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This is my SPARK_HOME:

```
$ echo $SPARK_HOME
/opt/spark
```

My environment:

- **Python 3.7.5** (I use pyenv if it matters)
- **Java adoptopenjdk-8.jdk** (installed via Homebrew. I also have adoptopenjdk-11.jdk stored in the same folder if it matters)
- **PySpark 2.4.0**
- **MacOS BigSur 11.5.2**
- **PyCharm Pro 2021.1.3**

I read several related guides, but none of them helped for now.
I'll be very appreciated for any help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.4.0 will require Java 8, which you have on your system, but it looks like PyCharm is not using this version, even if available. I had a similar problem with Eclipse, which defaulted to the last version of Java, which created compatibility issues, which I suspect in your application.

Are you running your app from PyCharm? If so can you display the environment values from there?

How have you installed Spark? You mention brew for Java, did you also use brew for Spark? If not, maybe it’s worth a try as dependencies are really tricky.

What happens when you run `java -version` in a shell? Can you try to uninstall Java 11 and maybe reinstall Java 8?

I hope this few advice can help.